# How to count total elements from aggregation results mongo db java with pagination?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Example of document:

```
{
"_id":{
  "$oid":"5e6abd223034d0a2823bdd8c"
},
"field_a":"123",
"client":"client"
},
{
"_id":{
  "$oid":"5e6abd223034d0a2823bdd8a"
 },
"field_a":"1234",
"field_b":"aaaa",
"client":"client"
},
{
"_id":{
  "$oid":"5e6abd223034d0a2823bdd8f"
},
"field_a":"12345",
"field_b":"aaaa",
"client":"client"
}}
```

And here is my code:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria("client").is(client);
query.addCriteria(criteria);

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.match(criteria),
    Aggregation.group("client", "field_b").addToSet("field_a").as("field_a"),
    Aggregation.skip((long) (paging.getPageNumber() * paging.getPageSize())),
    Aggregation.limit(paging.getPageSize())
);

List<MyClass> data = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "documents", MyClass.class).getMappedResults();
PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(data, paging, () -> mongoTemplate.count(query, MyClass.class));
```

And result:

```
{
total: 3
content: {
{
"field_a":"123",
"client":"client"
},
{
"field_a":"1234",
"field_b":"aaaa",
"client":"client"
},}
}
```

Total should be 2. Because when I use pagination for example if I want 1 element by page I will have 3 pages,but I should have 2.

So I need to group data by field_b and get number of total elements with grouped data. As result of my code I get number 3. But I should get 2. How can I add this condition group by to mongotemplate.count() ? Or is there any other solution ?

Comment: Can you please provide a small set of the expected result set?

Comment: Iv tried also to add in aggregation: Aggregation.count().as("count")   Then I get good number of total elements but content is null :(